# Compile C shared object with C++ files

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, g++

I have a C shared object (.so file) and i can only compile it using gcc because it uses C only functions like strcpy_s.

And i have a C++ code that contain some C++ only libraries.

Is that possible to compile the shared object with gcc and my code with g++ together ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can **link** your C++ program with your shared C library. Just make sure that you tell the C++ compiler that the functions in that library have C linkage by adding `extern "C" { ... }` around the functions in your C library's header file:

*shared_c_lib.h*

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// all your C functions declarations/prototypes

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

Comment: And there is nothing preventing use of C run-time library functions (like the named strcpy_s) in C++. It may run afoul of local coding guidelines but it is certainly legal within the language.